# How to get image path being saved using Universal Image Loader in android

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using **`Android Universal Image Loader`** to download and then save the downloaded image to my sd card using :

```
.diskCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir ))
```

Where **`cacheDir`**:

```
    File filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String dir = "/myIMAGESdir";
    File cacheDir = new File(filePath, dir);
    if(!(cacheDir.exists())){
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }
```

It is saving the images in the respective directory , as its suppose to do. **But now i want the path of that saved image** so that i can make use of it like saving that path to my **`DB`** or like that.

Comment: Check : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/673

Comment: Thnx @HareshChhelana, m trying and will let u know if something goes worng.

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = imageloader.getDiscCache().get(url);
String path = file.getAbsoluteFile();
```